# ChromeCast enabled App. check

Tags: chromecast

before buying a ChromeCast device , I would like to ask somebody to do me favor and check if the below App. are ChromeCast enabled or not ? 
thanks in advance

Telewebion
GLWiz
Manoto
IRIB

Comment: Such questions are not encouraged in a developer platform! it just increases noise among sound.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because not programming question

Answer (score 0):

As long as u have Android device you can mirror screen with your phone :)